# Responsive two column grid into one alternating rows

Tags: html, css

I would like to create the following responsive grid structure, taking in mind that element 3 and 5 are not always present and they have variable height.:

[grid image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOuEv.png)

I've tried with floating elements, but element 2 get's into the second column:
https://jsfiddle.net/a2tbbs2b/2/

CSS:

```
.panel{
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}

.panel::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.section{
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.section.left{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}

.one{
  background: green;
  height: 80px;
}

.two{
  background: blue;
  height: 70px;
}

.three{
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
}

.four{
  background: brown;
  height: 20px;
}

.five{
  background: yellow;
  height: 50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="section three">3</div>
  <div class="section left one">1</div>
  <div class="section four">4</div>
  <div class="section left two">2</div>
  <div class="section five">5</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying not to duplicate HTML to create this layout.

Any help is welcome. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You need to look into flexbox or CSS-Grid. The latter would be best probably.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#main {
    width: 98vw;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
}
#main div{ margin:5px;}
.flex-1{flex:1;}
.flex-2{flex:2;}
.flex-3{flex:3;}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class='flex-2' style="background-color:coral;">RED</div>
  <div class='flex-3' style="background-color:lightblue;">BLUE</div>  
  <div class='flex-1'></div>
  <div class='flex-1' style="background-color:lightgreen;">Green div with more content.
</div>
```

you can add the content in their specific containers .I am unable to understand your numbering scheme , but you can add content likewise.
[Read More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)